# Pass TextBox input to variable in ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: asp.net, variables, input, textbox, master-pages

I can easily pass the textbox input to a variable in an HTML form, but things don't work when using a master page and ContentPlaceHolder.

My Master page is "Site.Master"
My sister page is "Page1.aspx"

In it I have asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server", with textBox1.

How to get that input ?

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string MyContent = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

This action returns the original text of TextBox1 but not what the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, of course...
I forgot the  "if (!Page.IsPostBack)" in Page_Load.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Textbox has runat="server" property like

```
<asp:textbox id="txtName" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: It's in there. I edited my post to add part of code.